# Django circular import dependency between Model and Custom querysets

Tags: django, django-models

I'm using some complex Raw Querysets, and I separated the Model and the Model Custom Queryset in 2 separated files.

In Model I need to import the custom queryset:

```
objects = OwnerModelQuerySet.as_manager()
```

For each method of the custom queryset class I use:

```
 Owner.objects.raw(
```

so I need to import the model. So I have a circular dependency issues.
Is there any way in the custom queryset to access/get the model without directlly using the name ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't need to import the model into the queryset file. In your queryset methods, you can access the model via `self.model`.

But in any case, if the queryset is attached to Owner as a manager, `Owner.objects` *is* ownerModelQueryset, so you can do `self.raw` without needing to reference the model at all.